# The slowliness of the end of the animation with QPropertyAnimation

Tags: c++, qt

i want to display an animation of the slider with QPropertyAnimation, but i have a problem: at the end of the animation, the passage from a picture to an other be slower than at the first

this is my code

```
QPropertyAnimation *animation = new QPropertyAnimation(ui->sliderSlices,"sliderPosition");
animation->setDuration(1000);
animation->setStartValue(ui->sliderSlices->value()));
animation->setEndValue(maxSlice);
animation->setEasingCurve(QEasingCurve::OutCubic);


animation->start();
```

is there anyone who can find a solution ?

Comment: If that is the only animation to switch between all of you images, use [`setEasingCurve(QEasingCurve::Linear);`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qeasingcurve.html#Type-enum) This might be the issue because `OutCubic` will start slow and then accelerate with each frame.

Comment: thanks a lot, it's working perfectly